# Type 'std::default_random_engine' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I want to generate some random double numbers using default_random_engine and uniform_real_distribution in header random.

I use Eclipse for C/C++ & MinGW to build my project.

- Eclipse version: 4.2.1
- Eclipse CDT C/C++ Development Tools version: 8.1.1.201209170703
- Eclipse CDT GCC Cross Compiler Support version: 1.1.0.201209170703
- MinGW version: 4.6.2(checked using "gcc -v")

When I type std::default_random_engine in the editor, Eclipse prompts me that "Type 'std::default_random_engine' could not be resolved".

I have already configured my project to support C++11 features

- [Open Project Properties->C/C++ Build ->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other Flags. Put "-std=c++0x" at the end](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features)
- [Project Properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros->[Providers] tab->your Built-in Compiler Settings provider (toolchain dependent). Click on "Workspace Settings" link which gets you to "Settings" property page, select [Discovery] tab and your provider again. There is "Command to get compiler specs", add "-std=c++0x" in there.](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/373462/909018/#msg_909018)

Then I wrote a list initialized vector and a range for to test the support of the C++11, the code work fine.

```
    vector<int> ivec = {1, 2, 3};
    for (int i : ivec)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
```

What's wrong with the "std::default_random_engine", what should I do to fix this?

Comment: It is possible that the libstdc++ that comes with your compiler does not support the newer standard library features, but that your compiler does support the newer language features.

Comment: try std::tr1::default_random_engine

Comment: You _do_ include `<random>`? Also, even if Eclipse doesn't recognize it, does it build properly anyway?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hah +10, See if it compiles before complaining about *Eclipse*'s non-working C++11 IDE.

Comment: Sorry for replying your guys so late. I'm learning using this website and not familiar with it yet.

Please look at the first answer below. I agree with it. 

And Eclipse builds properly even if it doesn't recognize it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  It's been a long time since I posted the original answer and it has become outdated. I double-checked today (Mar 15, 2014): in Eclipse Kepler  (Build id 20130614-0229) it is sufficient to

- add under *Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings* then on the *Tool Settings* tab  *GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous* the `-std=c++11` flag,
- then under *Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Settings* on the *Discovery* tab chose *CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings* and add the `-std=c++11` flag to *Command to get compiler specs*. On my machine it looks like this after the change:

  `${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"`
- clean and rebuild both your project **and** your index (*Project > C/C++ Index > Rebuild*) as Eclipse tends to cache error messages and show them even though they are gone after changing the settings.

**This works on my machine for sure.** If it doesn't on yours, then you might want to give a shot to this: [C++11 full support on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22074724/341970) although I am neither sure about the correctness of this approach nor was it necessary to do it on my machine. As of March 7, 2014 users [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074724/c11-full-support-on-eclipse#comment33807529_22074724) that it helped them whereas the above approach didn't.

---

<sub>The original post, now outdated:</sub>

It seems to be a false error from the IDE.

Click on the project properties, then C/C++ General > Code Analysis > Syntax and Semantic Errors and deselect *Type cannot be resolved*.

I also had to disable a bunch of other Syntax and Semantic Errors, such as Invalid arguments, Invalid overload, Symbol is not resolved, etc. in my own projects. These bogus errors come from [Codan](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis).

(You might have to add `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` to your defines / preprocessor macros, not sure about this one though.)

Comment: And did it help? Does the same code compile outside the Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks a lot! And sorry for replying your answer so late.
At the very start I wondered that if there are some ways milder, but recently I meet some more such errors and so I do as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry I'm learning using this website. And I want to edit my comment bu it said "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes".
I didn't see your reply and I delete my first comment.

It do helps a lot. Now the errors disappear.

I haven't try to compile the code outside the Eclipse

Comment: BTW, Eclipse builds properly even if it doesn't recognize it

Comment: @zyy7259 Most C++ IDE's have, at the present, rather lacking support for C++11. Haven't found one yet that I wasn't able to trip up somehow.

Comment: @Cubic I choose Eclipse just because I like its UI :)