# C++11 full support on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I am trying to find a way to get full C++11 support on Eclipse.

In Eclipse Juno I had a lot of new features with `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` but I didn't find support for `std::threads`, `std::mutex`, etc.

How can I have completion for all C++11 functions?

**EDIT : Solution**

Go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols -> Tab [Symbols]`.
Add the symbol : **__cplusplus** with the value **201103L**

Comment: I have no problems with Eclipse Kepler. But it did require adding quite a lot of symbols to the configuration. What are you finding it doesn't do?

Comment: This : "std::mutex _myMutex;" produces a "Type 'std::mutex' could not be resolved" error on Eclipse Juno

Comment: In the end I used gcc to spit out all it's defined symbols, as my build would have, and then inserted them into eclipse. It spat out a LOT of symbols, but either manually inserting them or writing a little app to convert it to XML for eclipse to import them sorted my C++11 issues. gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null will do it. Though use the actual compiler and compiler flags your build really uses.

Comment: Note that IDE is not necessary related to a specific toolchain.

Comment: I don't really get your answer "Joe". How did you manage to solve the C++11 issues in Eclipse using gcc symbols? I don't think that all the symbols given by "gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null" are linked to C++11.

Comment: @Joe Interesting. I have been trying to solve this for 3 years... Did that resolve ALL of the problems? The most upvoted [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9131763/341970) didn't help me. And into which XML should those define be added? Could you share your app with us?

Comment: @Jerk31 Many of those symbols are C++11 related. Regarding your question, how do you mean *"there is no support for std::thread"*? Does your code compile? The IDE sure gives you [false positives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131939/341970), but did you try compiling it? Because it probably will, despite the bogus error messages.

Comment: It compiles yes. I've post a working solution in my edit. It's solved ;)

Comment: @Jerk31 Good to know, I will also give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: @Ali Yes. It sorted out all my problems but then I'm cross-compiling to an embedded platform, so I need to match the Eclipse indexers view of the world to my remote compilers. The "Paths and Symbols" config section of Eclipse lets you import and export settings. That file is a trivial xml file.

Comment: @Jerk31 The accepted answer and your edit says different things. Which one solved your problem?

Comment: @Ali : yes we discussed with Petr Budnik about this subject in a private conversation and we went to the conclusion that the solution I posted in "edit" was the best one. As this conversation gave me the solution I marked it as "accepted answer".

Comment: @Jerk31 OK, thanks, I will give it a shot. Unfortunately, I remember having problems with C++03 codes as well... :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eclipse works with C+11 support (Indexer and such) just fine: both Juno and Kepler. The thing is that you have to let Eclipse know that you are going to compile with C++11 support. This is done by providing additional flag `-std=c++11` to `CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings` in `C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery [tab]` so it will read something like:

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}" -std=c++11
```

And that is all you have to do with Kepler/Juno to get C++11 code highlighted correctly.

Note, this is workspace-wide setting. You can do the same on per project basis if you don't want to set it in workspace.

Comment: Still doesn't work for std::thread, std::condition_variable, etc

Comment: After you did that, did you refresh and re-index? Because, I'm looking at `std::thread test;` right now and it's properly highlighted and gives hovering help. Might worth trying closing and re-opening the project too... You have the last Juno update, I assume.

Comment: Maybe, I should add that I use Eclipse Kepler right now. But it worked in Juno for me too, I am quite sure of it. Oh, and with this you do not need to define `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` symbol... And just to be certain, you have the headers available to Eclipse? I mean, it does find standard `thread` and `mutex` headers in include path?

Comment: It's just super weird, Eclipse is finding the headers but says "Type 'std::mutex' could not be resolved" even if I create again the project...

Comment: Can you open, say, the `mutex` header and see what Eclipse highlighted as active code? The header has a few `#ifdef` on different constants like `__cplusplus`. Highlighting active code sections will tell you what Eclipse thinks about these values... You mentioned you are on Ubuntu. Are you using `gcc`? Which version if I may ask?.. Also, Eclipse requires to hit `Apply` every time you leave a tab. Just double check you have `-std=c++11` for the new project you created in its properties in `CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings`.

Comment: Using gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1.
When I open "<mutex>" I see at the beginning `#if __cplusplus < 201103L # include <bits/c++0x_warning.h> ` and then `else...` in gray color. Does that mean that my "__cplusplus" variable doesn't fill the requirements?

Comment: No, it's good. Gray color means this is inactive code. It means Eclipse recognizes C++ version no less than  C++11 (201103 = 2011, March, which is when committee approved C++11)... `gcc` version is fine too. It must be some glitch in Eclipse indexer, I'd say. Try right clicking on project and `Index -> Freshen All Files` and then `Index -> Rebuild`.

Comment: I've found a SUPER UGLY solution working !! `#undef __cplusplus  
#define __cplusplus 201900L`. Thanks for everything :)

Comment: Wow, hold on. `__cplusplus` is a standard macro defined by compilers. Adding `-std=c++11` as we discussed makes indexer to assume (so to speak) that compiler defines that macro to `201103L` (among other things) to use C++11. To redefine this macro is a very UGLY and DANGEROUS  hack indeed because standard headers and 3rd party libraries might rely on this value to be equal `201103L` exactly. You might not being able to compile after that... There is something wrong with your Eclipse CDT installation. You should not be needing such hack to get the proper indexing...

Comment: Huh you're right : `/usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdio:119:11: error: '::gets' has not been declared
   using ::gets;` 
But the indexer gets good values... Any other ideas?

Comment: Let's talk in chat, ok?

Comment: @lapk i did all this and nothing seems to work, the compiler is still using -std=c++98 flag, I have messed around with this for days. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Pavel By "all this" you mean the method described in the post, not in comments? Because comments describe an ugly hack... The way it is described in the post should work. Are you sure your Eclipse installation is not broken?

Comment: @lapk yes, post, how could it be broken? I have eclipse neon. I tried the eclipse juno as well, and it's still the same :(

Comment: @Pavel Just so we have an understanding: these settings are only for code highlighting/indexer and such in editor, not actual compiler flags for compilation. Compilation flags are set elsewhere.

Comment: @lapk oh, I see, that makes sense.

Comment: I found that in some cases, this is not enough, and the C++ Builder dialect also needs to be set to C++11, as in this post https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/470456/

Answer (score -1):

Is there even a compiler which *fully* supports C++11? If you are on Windows, then I think you should give [Microsoft Visual Studio Express Edition 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs) a try. Its C++11 support is not complete but IMO fairly good, and it looks like it will get even better in the near future.

Comment: OK, I rest my case  then :)