# "Function 'stoi' could not be resolved" in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, c++11, g++

I'm using 64bit Ubuntu with the G++ Compiler.
I've tried the various posts that cover enabling C++11, and what I did so far is:
Added `-std=c++11` to Cross G++ Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other Flags
Added `-std=c++0x` to C/C++-General->Preprocessor Include Paths/Macros-> CDT GCC Built-In Compiler Settings -> "Command to get Compiler Specs"
and moved "CDT GCC Built-In Compiler Specs" all the way to the top. (I have also tried adding `-std=c++11` to CDT GCC Built-In Compiler Settings)

I re-resolved unresolved includes, included the correct headers, and still: std::stoi is not resolved.
The code does however compile if I compile without eclipse, using just the G++ and a makefile.
The Version of my G++ is 4.8.2.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of it?

Comment: Eclipse is a glorified editor. You need to know what compiler version you are using.

Comment: Sorry, the g++ version is 4.8.2.

Comment: Oh sorry, your error *is* an Eclipse error, not a compiler error. Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074724/c11-full-support-on-eclipse) can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue resolved! It wasn't the symbol, but apparently re-resolving wasn't the right thing to do, I had to re-index.