# Configure C++11 on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using Eclipse Kepler for development of C++ , lately I have been working on C++11 , with earlier threads ([C++11 full support on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074724/c11-full-support-on-eclipse)) I have configured C++11 in Eclipse. 
But I am unable to compile a basic program :

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> arr = {2, 3, 5};

}
```

Error :
1./usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error Th**is file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.**
2.  ../src/HelloWorld.cpp:19:5: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'

But when I run from command Prompt using  " g++ -std=gnu++11 xyz.cpp " , it is compiling sucessfully .

Please Help me how do I make my eclipse Kepler work with C++11 .

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project on Project Explorer -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings.

In the Tools settings tab, there is a GCC C++ Compiler item. Expand it and select Settings -> Miscesllaneous.

Append at the end of the Other Flags text input the string -std=c++11

This should be done for any configuration you need.

Answer (score 3):

Paolo M answer is correct in order to turn on c++11 on a per-project basis.
You can also enable c++11 (or any standard) by default for all projects.

In `Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Settings > 'Discovery' tab`
Select your compiler (eg. CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW) and add the `-std=c++11` option.

The result can looks like `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -std=c++11 -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"`