# std vector at could not resolve on eclipse CDT GCC Builtin Compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I have problem with **CDT GCC Builtin Compiler** (not with the code).
Here is a small example that this issue is happen.
I have this code in eclipse:

```
#include <vector>

typedef struct tal{
    tal()
    :a(0), b(0)
    {};
    int a;
    int b;
} Tal;

int main() {
    std::vector<Tal> tal_vec;
    Tal tt;
    tal_vec.push_back(tt);
    Tal tt2 = tal_vec.at(0);
    tt2.a;
    
    int c = tal_vec.at(0).a;
}
```

At the last statement: `int c = tal_vec.at(0).a;`
Eclipse tell me: `Field 'a' could not be resolved`.

Already tell CDT GCC Builtin Compiler add this: `-std=c++11` flag like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074724/c11-full-support-on-eclipse)

In the other statement you can see that there is no error if i tell eclipse to go `Tal tt2 = tal_vec.at(0);` the after that to get filed a value.

can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Why are you using `typedef` in C++ to define a type-name of a class? The actual class-name `tal` is already a type-name.

Comment: `typedef class tal`  Reading too many `C` books?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that code you posted will even compile - it is because including `tal's` constructor, everything else is `private` in this class. You can't even create a single object of class `tal` according to above situation.

I run above code in ideone and following are compiler errors,

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:4: error: 'tal::tal()' is private
prog.cpp:13: error: within this context
prog.cpp:7: error: 'int tal::a' is private
prog.cpp:16: error: within this context
prog.cpp:7: error: 'int tal::a' is private
prog.cpp:18: error: within this context
```

Comment: Then its problem with eclipse that why it is flagging for a valid statement - given that you have made all members public in above code

Comment: I know the problem on eclipse. I need a solution for eclipse CDT built in compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make it `public`.

```
#include <vector>

typedef class tal{
public:
    tal()
    :a(0), b(0)
    {};
    int a;
    int b;
} Tal;

int main() {
    std::vector<Tal> tal_vec;
    Tal tt;
    tal_vec.push_back(tt);
    Tal tt2 = tal_vec.at(0);
    tt2.a;

    int c = tal_vec.at(0).a;
}
```

Worked fine in **Code::BLocks 13.12**

Comment: I change the code example.
The code is compile, but eclipse show unresolved in Eclipse.
The problem it on Eclipse. please help.

Comment: Haven't tested in Eclipse. Let me Check

Answer (score 0):

in C++, interior of class is private by default :

```
class T
{
    int a;
    int b;
private:
    int c;
public:
    int d;
protected:
    int e;
}
```

Here, a, b and c, are "private", therefore you cannot access it outside the class.

However, you can access d from everywhere, just by telling variable.d = ...;

For e, only what inherits from T can use it.

This is true for variables, functions etc.